# Split String into Fixed Number of Words Recursively [Java]

Tags: java, list, arraylist, split

I am attempting to split a `String` (stored in `ArrayList`) into fixed number of words (not characters) recursively.

For example, suppose I have the an `ArrayList` which contains the following two `String` phrases:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("key1 key2 key3 key4 key5 key6 key7");
words.add("key11 key12 key13 key14 key15 key16 key17");
```

And I want to split into chunks of 5 words (`int desiredListSize = 5;`) - this would produce the following two lists:

LIST 1:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word2 word3 word4 word5 word6
word3 word4 word5 word6 word7
```

LIST 2:

```
word11 word12 word13 word14 word15
word12 word13 word14 word15 word16
word13 word14 word15 word16 word17
```

Each list above would then be added to List of Lists array so the output would be in format: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>()`

So far the following code fragment solves most of the problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public static void splitListIntoWords()
{

    int desiredListSize = 5;
    final ArrayList<String> textWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    textWords.add("key1 key2 key3 key4 key5 key6 key7");
    textWords.add("key11 key12 key13 key14 key15 key16 key17");


    final List<List<String>> listOfLists = textWords.stream().flatMap(w -> {

        final String[] wordList = StringX.splitStrIntoWordsRtrnArr(w); // w.split(" ");

        int calculatedListSize = (wordList.length < desiredListSize) ? wordList.length : desiredListSize;

        return  IntStream.range(0, Math.min(wordList.length - (calculatedListSize - 1), wordList.length)).mapToObj(i -> i ).flatMap(i -> Stream.of(
                IntStream.range(i, Math.min(i+desiredListSize, wordList.length)).mapToObj(j -> wordList[j])
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
    })          .collect(Collectors.toList());


    for (int counter = 0; counter < listOfLists.size(); counter++) {

        System.out.println("LIST: " + counter);


        System.out.println(listOfLists.get(counter).toString());
    }

}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
LIST: 0
[key1, key2, key3, key4, key5]
LIST: 1
[key2, key3, key4, key5, key6]
LIST: 2
[key3, key4, key5, key6, key7]
LIST: 3
[key11, key12, key13, key14, key15]
LIST: 4
[key12, key13, key14, key15, key16]
LIST: 5
[key13, key14, key15, key16, key17]
```

However the ideal output is:

```
LIST 0:
key1 key2 key3 key4 key5
key2 key3 key4 key5 key6
key3 key4 key5 key6 key7

LIST 1: 
key11 key12 key13 key14 key15
key12 key13 key14 key15 key16
key13 key14 key15 key16 key17
```

Both lists above should then be added to `listOfLists`.

Notice how in the *desired output* each list stores the result of operation on String: `key1 key2 key3 key4 key5` as a single `String` (with a space between each word) **NOT as a list**.

In other words, when one calls `listOfLists.get(0);` one should obtain a list that contains the results of operation on `words.add("key1 key2 key3 key4 key5 key6 key7");` and when one calls `listOfLists.get(1);` one should obtain results of operation on `words.add("key11 key12 key13 key14 key15 key16 key17");` Of course, if there's more than two entries in original `textWords` List then `listOfLists` will contain a corresponding number of lists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.S. I don't have time right now to refine my posting, but here's the better (I think) of the original postings. I may get back tomorrow sometime, but I've got a job that needs doing too :-)

Anyway, here it is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("key1 key2 key3 key4 key5 key6 key7");
        words.add("key11 key12 key13 key14 key15 key16 key17");

        final List<List<String>> listOfLists = words.stream().flatMap(w -> {

            final String[] wordList = w.split(" ");

            return  IntStream.range(0, Math.min(  3, wordList.length)).mapToObj(i ->          i ).flatMap(i -> Stream.of(
                    IntStream.range(i, Math.min(i+5, wordList.length)).mapToObj(j -> wordList[j])
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
        })          .collect(Collectors.toList());

        listOfLists.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was waiting for you:) Up-voted and accepted.. Thanks!!